# Flutter Inherited Widget updateShouldNotify oldWidget same as the new one?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, inherited-widget

I am trying to deep dive into inherited widget and got stuck somewhere. When i debug on updateShouldNotify method, its parameter(old widget) has same data with the new one. Also the instances are same. Due to that contition always false and my dependent widgets dont rebuild.

I put my simple code on dartpad. Can you spot the problem that i am doing?

just push the increase from profile

https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

Thanks

Comment: @hasankaraman it it not related with that

Comment: Sorry, I was going to write on someone else's question. I wrote to yours